# DNS not working / How to determine which program/service is defining network configuration?

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns

I have a client ubuntu 18.04 PC which is connected to the internet but DNS is not working. At first I thought I would have to configure the netplan yaml file which I did like:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.246.5.248/24]
      gateway4: 10.246.5.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.246.5.1, 127.0.0.53]
        search: [<my_domain_name>]
```

`sudo netplan --debug apply` returned no errors and I restarted network-manager, but the network configuration doesn't change no matter how I edit the yaml file.

Then, following the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112378/netplan-configuration-doesnt-seem-to-be-taking-effect), I removed the ethernets configuration from the yaml file, edited my /etc/network/interfaces and restarted the network-manager, but again no changes in the IP address and name servers are being made.

Then, I've tried to run `nm-connection-editor`. No interfaces where being listed there, so I've tried adding one interface with my configurations. Again no changes in network configuration, even after restarting the network-manager.

My /etc/resolv.conf file has a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf. If I edit the stub with my DNS configuration, the DNS starts working, but only until I reboot.

Did I miss something? My guess is that there's other service/program that is changing the resolv.conf. How do I determine which is and configure my DNS there?

Comment: Is this a Desktop or Server installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is a **Desktop** installation, and not a **Server** installation...

Undo the changes that you made to /etc/network/interfaces

Edit your netplan .yaml to look like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Then use the NetworkManager GUI to configure your ethernet interface with your fixed address.

Here are examples using nm-connection-editor (use the regular NetworkManager GUI if you like):

Use the **Device** pop up to select your ethernet MAC address...

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's linux, service ??? restart, don't reboot

Comment: @PavelNiedoba For fixed IP addresses, you must reboot (not restart). Please change your down vote for my ACCEPTED answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already in your posted configuration.

The line `renderer: NetworkManager` says that all network configuration is to be handled by NetworkManager, the utility on the system to configure things there.  What you need to do is remove your additional netplan configuration you added for your interface and remove any `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration you may have set up, and then configure your network interfaces in Network Manager.

The DNS is handled by `systemd-resolved` as part of SystemD, the stub resolver item is fine there.

You can get the current DNS servers you're using by running `systemd-resolve --status` and look out for "DNS Servers" lines.